# Python : how to have multiple threads wait on an event?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python application where one thread acts like a master, it runs an algorithm once a second.  I have a number of slave/peer threads, I'd like each one of them to be paused until each time the master thread processes it's one second cycle.

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: So the slave/peer threads are running only for the brief moment that the master thread is starting over?  I'm sorry I don't fully understand the question.  It sounds like your master thread is a loop and you want to execute a background function at the end of each loop?

Comment: Master thread and peer threads are infinite loops.  I want to synchronize the peer threads so they tick over in sync with the master thread.

Comment: [Queue.Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is almost always the best way to communicate between [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) (or [processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), the API is the same).

Answer (score 2):

There is an event construct:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects

Let master thread own one event for each slave thread. At the beginning of tick master sets all of them. Each slave starts his tick by waiting for this event. When waiting is over, it unsets his event.

Comment: OK so I would definitely need one event per slave thread, no way for them to share a single event?